# Hide View until Button is pressed

Tags: java, android

I want to hide a View until a Button is pressed without the whole effort of creating a blank view and switching between them. How can I do this?

Comment: You can use `android:visibility="invisible"` in your xml file and then    use `tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` in `Button` `onClickListener` !

Answer (score 2):

Set the view's visibility on GONE when rendered.
On the onclick from the button that reveals the view set the view to VISIBLE

```
hiddenView = (View) findViewById(R.id.hidden_view);
hiddenView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

showButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_button);

showButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //when showButton is clicked show hidden_view
        hidden_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```